# Gridview with Enable and Disable image buttons

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-ajax

I have gridview in an asp.net application. I want to insert a column with image buttons where by click on it will enable or disable users or change the status field in db and also change the image button image accordingly user status.

Meaning: I want to display different images for disabled and enabled users.

How can I do this in C# and bind the data to the image button?

Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the ItemDataBound event.  This is where you can check each row of your grid and apply changes to it.  Then you can hide / unhide or change buttons:

VB.net below but you can easily convert to C#:

```
            Dim ib As ImageButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ibFav"), ImageButton)
            ib.Visible = False
            Dim ib2 As ImageButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ibRemFav"), ImageButton)
            ib2.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample User Model:

```
public class UserModel {    
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the GridView Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    onrowcommand="GridView_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="EnabledImgBtn" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                    CommandName="ResetUserState" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
         //Other columns....
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Set the 'CommandArgument' according to your needs. e.g the ID of the User.
Sample Code-behind for the gridview:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack){
        LoadGridView();
    }
}

private void LoadGridView()
{
    this.GridView.DataSource = GetUsersFromDatabase();
    this.GridView.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var user = e.Row.DataItem as UserModel;
        var enabledImgBtn = e.Row.FindControl("EnabledImgBtn") as ImageButton;
        if (enabledImgBtn != null)
            enabledImgBtn.ImageUrl = user.IsEnabled ? "~/YourImagePath/enabled.png"
                                                    : "~/YourImagePath/disalbed.png";
    }
}

protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ResetUserState")
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument!= null)
           { 
            var userName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();            
            //Change user enabled state and Update database
            //Sample code:
             var user = FindUserByName("userName");
             user.IsEnabled = !user.IsEnabled;
             //SaveInDatabase(user);
             LoadGridView();
           }
    }
}
```

You may consider using 'CommandField' with Type equal to 'Image' instead of 'TemplateField', but there is an issue with this approach, [read more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19942/ASP-NET-GridView-Image-Command-Button-Problem-Mult).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    onrowcommand="GridView_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">

    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="GrdItemImg">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnChangeActiveStatus" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RecordID")%>'
                                    CommandName='GRDSTATUS' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# getStatusImage(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsApproved"))) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Col2" HeaderText="Col2" />
         //Other Respective  columns....
                ...........
                ..........
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And In CS file add the following function.

```
public string getStatusImage(int intStatus)
    {
        string strStatus = string.Empty;

        if (intStatus == 1)
        {            
            strStatus = "~/images/active.png";
        }
        else
        {
            strStatus = "~/images/inactive.png";
        }

        return strStatus;
    }
```

So on the base of "intStatus" respective active / InActive Image will be set.